# Export MySQL DB dump from Kubernetes container running in a pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a pod running two containers, one of them is mysql container. I want to take dbdump from mysql container running in the pod and save that file dbdump on my system.

So that dbdump is coming out to my system from container running inside a pod

```
mysqldump --user="user" --password="Password" abc_database > dbdump.sql
```

Comment: use kubectl cp <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/foo /tmp/bar

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl exec` the command and redirect the output to a file. The redirection will occur locally on your system

```
kubectl exec deployment/mysql -- \
  mysqldump --user="user" --password="Password" abc_database > dbdump.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Login into the pod

`kubectl exec -it <pod> -n <namespace> -- /bin/bash`

2. Run `mysqldump` from within the pod and use tmp to write the file

`mysqldump <-u user> -p <db> > /tmp/file.sql`

3. Copy the file from the pod

`kubectl cp <namespace>/<pod>:/tmp/file.sql file.sql`